# ООП в php. Синтаксическая ошибка.

Tags: ооп, php

Здравствуйте! Учусь по книге, там был код работы ООП в php, попытка вывести это код закончилась синтаксической ошибкой. Что неправильно?

```
<?php
class Car
{
  var $gas = 0;
  function addGas($amount)
  {
    $this->gas = $this->gas + $amount;
    echo "в бак залито $amount галлонов бензина";
    //>
  }
?>
```

Comment: @angers777, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Ага. И поправьте количество begin-end-ов.

Comment: @angers777 у тебя не хватает фигурной скобки.

Comment: А по-моему, ООП в PHP само по себе ошибка.

Comment: @karmadro4, это чисто Ваше индивидуальное мнение, и, вообще, Вы по-моему никакого отношения к PHP не имеете

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код рабочий. Только фигурной скобки в конце описания класса не хватает.

```
<?php
class Car
{
  var $gas = 0;
  function addGas($amount)
  {
    $this->gas = $this->gas + $amount;
    echo "в бак залито $amount галлонов бензина";
    //>
  }
}
$a=new Car();
$a->addGas(10);
?>
```

Вот проверил в консоли:

```
k@m:~$ php test_oop.php
в бак залито 10 галлонов бензина
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
class Car
{
  var $gas = 0;
  function addGas($amount)
  {
    $this->gas = $this->gas + $amount;
    echo "в бак залито $amount галлонов бензина";
    //>
  }
}
?>
```

Все правильно, просто пропущена последняя скобка.

Answer (score 0):

А где модификаторы доступа? Второе - var устарел, в strict-режиме будет выдавать ошибку. Пользуйтесь private/public/protected

Comment: то что устарел -согласен) Но тут нада узнать в какой версии работает человек

Comment: php4 кто-то еще использует? О_О

Comment: CodeIgniter, к примеру, использует var вместо модификаторов доступа. Пока на PHP5 переходить не собираются.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
class Car { 
    protected $gas = 0; 
    public function addGas($amount = 0) { 
        $this->gas = $this->gas + $amount; 
        echo "в бак залито '. $amount .' галлонов бензина";
    } 
}
$test = new Car();
$test->addGas(10);
$test->addGas(20);
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php 
class Car { 
    var $gas = 0; 
    function addGas($amount) { 
        $this->gas = $this->gas + $amount; echo "в бак залито {$amount} галлонов бензина";
    } 
}
$test=new Car();
$test->addGas(10);
?>
```